# Which is the NodeJS part in my react project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am working on a ReactJS project that has a Routes component, makes requests to the API with Axios, and then all the React/Redux components.

What part of this is Node? Is the Routes part Node, or the Axios? Or none?

Comment: Do you mean React Router `Route` components? If yes, then none of what you have listed is Node.js

Comment: The actual backend API may or may not be written in Node.js, and some of your developer tools probably will be, but none of the things you've listed run in Node.

Comment: Yes, @Tholle that is what I mean. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-router routes are more like a navigational tool for your frontend app. It allows you to tie the components that make up your app to dynamic routes which simplifies management as the app grows larger. The server knows nothing about these routes. They are not the same as static routes which most people are more familiar with, and which you would use in your node.js backend. Here the routes together with HTTP VERBs is used to tell the webserver what it should do with your request and what it should send back (using controllers or handlers in your backend).